# How to show turn by turn navigation in react-native or android

Tags: google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I am working on react-native app where I want to show turn by turn navigation to the user. I don't want to open google map on top of my app to show navigation. I want to show navigation in my app only.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Google Maps Platform terms of service prohibit using an API for real-time navigation.

Have a look at paragraph 3.2.4 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services. It reads:

> **(d) No Re-Creating Google Products or Features.** Customer will not use the Services to create a product or service with features that are substantially similar to or that re-create the features of another Google product or service. Customer’s product or service must contain substantial, independent value and features beyond the Google products or services. For example, Customer will not: (i) re-distribute the Google Maps Core Services or pass them off as if they were Customer’s services; (ii) create a substitute of the Google Maps Core Services, Google Maps, or Google Maps mobile apps, or their features; (iii) use the Google Maps Core Services in a listings or directory service or to create or augment an advertising product; **(iv) combine data from the Directions API, Geolocation API, and Maps SDK for Android to create real-time navigation functionality substantially similar to the functionality provided by the Google Maps for Android mobile app.**

source: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license

The only way compliant with Terms of Service is opening an Intent with Google Maps app in navigation mode.

I hope this clears up your doubt.